# Использование select, case, when, then и php

Tags: php, sql, select, case

Почему ничего не выводится ? может что-то  с синтаксисом не так?

---

```
$Data = dbArray(" SELECT name, data, value,
case
when value < ".$norma['name1'][0]." then 
".$norma['name1'][1]."
when value <= ".$norma['name2'][0]." then 
".$norma['name2'][1]."
end as norma
from t_temperature
where street ='Уманская' and age <= '50'")**
```

*
Суть кода в том ,чтобы при определенной температуре, он сравнивал её со значением глобальной переменной и выдавал письменный ответ "Норма" или "Болен"
слова Норма и Болен так же содержаться в массиве глобальной переменной

Comment: Может вы документацию откроете?

Comment: вы имеете в виду остальные файлики?

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT t.name, t.data, t.value,
    CASE
        WHEN t.value < " . $norma['name1'][0] . " THEN " . $norma['name1'][1] . "
        WHEN t.value <= " . $norma['name2'][0] . " THEN " . $norma['name2'][1] . "
    END norma
FROM t_temperature as t
WHERE street ='Уманская' and age <= '50';"
```